# Rewrite URL with nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, rewrite

Well, I'm using Ngix as reverse proxy and wso2 in backend. What I want to do is: access wso2's pages using a custom url on NGIX, but acessing the right URL on backend. Example when I access https://myngix/wso2am/publish, it should  send to backend address https://localhost:9443/publish, but I would like to keep my URL as https://myngix/wso2am/publish. Is it possible? Here, I have a sample that I try to achieve this, but didn't work:

```
upstream sslapi.am.wso2.com {
    server {node-ip-address}:9443;
}

upstream sslgw.am.wso2.com {
    server {node-ip-address}:8243;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.am.wso2.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://api.am.wso2.com/$1 permanent;

}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name api.am.wso2.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/{cert_name};
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/{key_name};
    location /wso2am {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_read_timeout 5m;
            proxy_send_timeout 5m;
            proxy_pass https://sslapi.am.wso2.com/publisher;
        }

        access_log /etc/nginx/log/am/https/access.log;
        error_log /etc/nginx/log/am/https/error.log;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name gw.am.wso2.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/{cert_name};
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/{key_name};
    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_read_timeout 5m;
            proxy_send_timeout 5m;
            proxy_pass https://sslgw.am.wso2.com;
        }

        access_log /etc/nginx/log/gw/https/access.log;
        error_log /etc/nginx/log/gw/https/error.log;
}
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I think you should be using `location /wso2am/` (with a trailing `/`) and `proxy_pass https://sslapi.am.wso2.com/;` (without `publisher` and just a trailing `/`).

Comment: Well, it partially works...because my URL on browser changed...NGINX sent request to correct address on backend. But, my url on brownser changed to  https://myngix/publish. And I'd like to keep original URL, in that case: https://myngix/wso2am/publish .I don't know if it is a behaviour from NGINX or WSO2.